# Form field still undefined after user changes input

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following snippet of javascript code which is supposed to act as my form validation to make sure that when a user submits a form that none of the fields are empty.The code works fine for "Detector_Type" as its default value is "".

However, when I add text to the next field "Name_and_Part_Number" and try to submit, the value still shows as 'undefined' in the console log, even though I have input text into the text field.

Why is this occurring and how do I go about making it so that when I input text it no longer becomes undefined?

EDIT 1: The data stored in the form is stored as a RoR variable which may make a difference.

JS Code:

```
function validateForm(formId)

 var fields = ["Detector_Type", "Name_and_Part_Number", "Type", "FPA_Size", "Pitch"]
 var errors = ["Detector Type", "Name and Part Number", "Type", "FPA Size", "Pitch"]
  var i, l = fields.length;
  var fieldname; 
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {    
    fieldname = fields[i];
    console.log(fieldname + ": " + document.getElementById(fieldname).value);
    if ((document.getElementById(fieldname).value === "") || (typeof document.getElementById(fieldname).value === 'undefined'))) {
      alert(errors[i] + " can not be empty");
      return false;
    }

  }
  return true;
 }  
}
```

HTML Code:

```
...
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Detector_Type %><br>
  <select class="flat-text" style="width: 240px;" name='spreadsheet[Detector_Type]'     id='Detector_Type' onclick="toggle_visibility('Detector_Type');" >
      <option value=''>Choose a category...</option>
      <option value="GMAPD">GMAPD</option>
      <option value="DFPA">DFPA</option>
      <option value="Other">Other </option>  
   </select> 

  </div>   

  <div class="field" id="Name_and_Part_Number">
    <%= f.label :Name_and_Part_Number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Name_and_Part_Number%>
  </div>
  <div class="field" id= "Type">
    <%= f.label :Type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field" id= "FPA_Size">
    <%= f.label :FPA_Size %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :FPA_Size %>
  </div>
  <div class="field" id= "Pitch">
    <%= f.label :Pitch %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Pitch %>
  </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just using rails :require => true validation without custom error messages

Answer (score 0):

The Field is a DIV, to access text value of HTML element you can use **innerHTML** attribute opposite to **value**.

Comment: I assume you mean in the "typeof..." condition of my code? If i change value to innerHTML there it still submits the from even if nothing is entered

Comment: In Div element attribute value is not defined.
To get value I suggest you to verify:
document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML == ""

Comment: If I add " value="" " to my DIV and then check: if ((document.getElementById(fieldname).value === "") || (document.getElementById(fieldname).innerHTML === "")) the form still submits if nothing is entered into the field. (Sorry if I am not understanding and implemented your suggestion incorrectly)

Comment: Also if i use (document.getElementById(fieldname).getAttribute('value') === "") as the second half of my check it catches the error, but upon editing the form it still thinks the value is ""

Comment: And if it is any help printing the innerHTML to console gives this: "Name_and_Part_Number: 
    <label for="spreadsheet_Name_and_Part_Number">Name and part    number</label><br>
    <input id="spreadsheet_Name_and_Part_Number" name="spreadsheet[Name_and_Part_Number]" type="text">
  "

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that each text_field is not empty you need to check the field not the div. You could just add a child selector to your javascript.

So something like

```
$('#id input').first().val()
```

would get you the input under that div and then it's value.

If all the fields are required for the form then you could just use a selector for all inputs then loop through them instead of looping through a static list of ID's.

Comment: Unfortunately not all of the fields are required (the above is a shortened list). Also are you suggesting replacing the second half of my 'or' with your code? If so that does not work either.

Comment: @JBarry465 Wel the question becomes are you using jquery or not? If so then you replace the whole or statement with something like `$('#id input').first().val() === '' || $('#id input').first().val() === undefined`

Comment: @JBarry465 Also another thought would be using HTML5 data attributes to designate which need validation, then use a selector such as `$('[data-validation = true]')` to get a list of elements that need to be validated and run through it.

Comment: I am using jquery very little as I do not really know it (pretty new to javascript as well). I can use "required: => true" in the rails field which gets the main job done, but that makes custom error messages a little harder to deal with.